# Laravel 5.8 dependecy injection - how to inject model to service

Tags: laravel-5, dependency-injection

I have **BooksService** class which should be injected by **Book model** object. Then I want to inject **BooksService to BookController**. But I dont know ho to do it.

I am getting an error Class App\Model\BookService does not exist. Is it neccesary to register it somewhere? Also I am not sure if I am doing it right. Is it in this code?

BookService

```
namespace App\Model;

class BookService
{
    /** @var  Book */
    public $books;


    // I am not sure if this is ok
    public function construct(Book $books)
    {
        $this->books = $books;
    }


    public function test()
    {
        dd($this->books);
    }

}
```

BookController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreBook;
use App\Model\Book;
use App\Model\BookService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class BookController extends Controller
{

    ....    

    // This throws me an error BookService does not exists
    public function create(BookService $bookService)  
    {
        $bookService->test();
        return view('book.create');
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that __contruct() method expects Book facade instance  but Laravel does not know what is it. Also Book facade is available from  inside the service class so no need to be injected to it.